# How to cancle auto brace in the latest IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

My IDEA version info :
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2
Build #IU-172.3317.76, built on July 15, 2017
In this version I got a annoying problem when I try to input a dot it will auto input a pair of brace,just like that:
[image]

Are there any solutions?

Comment: Please file a bug with the steps to reproduce and the sample code at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. Check if [these options](http://i.imgur.com/ry7tWbY.png) have any effect.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I've report that issue to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177182#u=1502162335767
and that will be fixed in the following version.